# OR operator on single column PDO

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm shifting my database connections from mysqli to PDO.
While updating,I'm stuck on one query:
In mysql its:

```
$quec='designation=10 OR designation=11 OR designation=12';
$query="select firstname,mobile,email from mt where location=".$value." and cp!=".$cpa" and (".$quec.") and dept=".$usersubdept." and mstatus=1";
```

Its working fine in mysqli.
In PDO i wrote:

```
$query="select firstname,mobile,email from mt where location=:value AND cp!=:cpa AND (:quec) AND dept=:usersubdept AND mstatus=:mstatus";
```

Binding the values with variables using bind syntax, I'm not getting any result row.
How to rectify the problem?

Comment: Any error are you getting? if not it must be binding problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use `:quec` as a parameter, since it is actually 3 things and not a value that can be bound.  Otherwise, you may have something wrong with how you're binding, perhaps, but we haven't seen your code for that. Try this:

```
$query="SELECT firstname, mobile, email FROM mt WHERE location = :value AND
cp != :cpa AND (" . $quec . ") AND dept = :dept AND mstatus = 1";

$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':value',$value);
$stmt->bindValue(':cpa',$cpa);
$stmt->bindValue(':dept',$usersubdept);

$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare a string like this: ':id0, :id1, :id2, you can do this like this:

```
$designationlist = ':id'.implode(',:id', array_keys($designationIds));
```

then your SQL will be:

```
$query="select firstname,mobile,email from mt where location=:value AND cp!=:cpa AND designation IN(".$designationlist.") AND dept=:usersubdept AND mstatus=:mstatus";
```

and:

```
$parms = array_combine(explode(",", $designationlist), $designationIds);
$stmt  = $PDO->prepare($query);
$res  = $stmt->execute($parms);
```